# How to get android system log from a Java program

Tags: java, android, logging

Does anyone know how to get the android device system log programatically using Java? This would be something similar to what is available on lower panel on the Dalvik Debug Monitor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want this access log output from inside your android app or from outside? Are you using the emulator or a device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untested with 'adb shell logcat', but I've used this to get other things from via adb:

```
public static String[] getAdbLogCat() {

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/adb shell logcat");
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        final StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        return (String[])arrList.toArray(new String[0]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new String[]{};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, that's exactly what I needed :) You rock!

Comment: Just for a quick info, 'adb shell logcat' works just fine, and so does 'adb logcat' :)

Comment: There's a couple minor errors in your code, but aside from that, when I got everything else working, I got this error:
Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied
Looking around StackOverflow and other places on the web, it seems this only works on rooted devices, which means it'll hardly work on any devices.  Is there a way to get logs without requiring root permission?

Comment: I figured out how to get it working.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I started with Mathias Conradt's answer above.  It didn't work for me, but after working with it for a long time, I found out what tweaks it needed to get it working right.  This will work.  It doesn't require root access, special permissions, or anything.

```
private static String getAdbLogCat()
{
    String log = "";
    String str;
    try
    {
        String myStringArray[]= {"logcat", "-d"};
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myStringArray);
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        str = br.readLine();
        while (str != null)
        {
            log += str;
            str = br.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
    return log;
}
```